# SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows

I am getting following error message when i write `sqlplus` on command prompt

```
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Here are the path details

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted my PC and tried setting ORACLE HOME from Command Prompt as `SET ORACLE_HOME=...` and it worked

Further more, i did following two things

1-`ORACLE_HOME` should not contain anything after the path i.e. no `\`, `;`,`,`

2-I added an environment variable named `LANG` with value `American_America.we8iso8859p15`